# jQuery setInterval delays from real time

Tags: javascript, jquery

It can be possible to make `setInterval` work with current time together?

I mean, I am making a custom countdown library for personal use, and I need to calculate each second for that, but sometimes `setInterval` delays from real time, I think it is because of browser lags or execution time. Or is there another better way for doing that?

An example of the execution time of my function, even if there is 1000 milliseconds, the time may vary:

`start: 898, end: 898, execution time: 0 index.js:92
start: 898, end: 899, execution time: 1 index.js:92
start: 899, end: 900, execution time: 1 index.js:92
start: 900, end: 901, execution time: 1 index.js:92
start: 904, end: 905, execution time: 1 index.js:92
start: 904, end: 905, execution time: 1 index.js:92
start: 905, end: 905, execution time: 0 index.js:92
start: 905, end: 905, execution time: 0 index.js:92
start: 906, end: 906, execution time: 0 index.js:92
start: 906, end: 907, execution time: 1 index.js:92
start: 892, end: 892, execution time: 0 index.js:92
start: 907, end: 907, execution time: 0 index.js:92
start: 907, end: 908, execution time: 1 index.js:92
start: 908, end: 908, execution time: 0 index.js:92
start: 908, end: 909, execution time: 1 index.js:92
start: 909, end: 910, execution time: 1 index.js:92`

Comment: just use 333ms instead of 1000 and re-paint if needed.

Comment: Timers aren't exact. The timeout/interval value is just a minimum wait time, and they can be delayed further or have intervals skipped entirely if the engine is already busy. http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: You could use requestAnimationFrame to create a more accurate timer.

Comment: @Denees What is the output supposed to be showing us? I think you need to post your code so we can understand the problem better.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks. I will mark your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't calculate the number of seconds at the beginning and try to decrease the number by one each tick.

Instead, figure out the ending time, then on each tick of the setInterval/setTimeout (which should probably be more often than once per second), calculate the amount of time between current time and the ending time.

Comment: still relying on setTimeout/setInterval, prone to delay

Comment: @Ejay The take away is to make the interval shorter so that it fires more than once per second and use actual time to calculate the remainder.

Comment: @Ejay Each individual tick may be prone to delay, but it won't get more inaccurate over time. I would think unless there was a LOT of javascript running, it would be correct within .1-.5 seconds at any given time.

Comment: @Ejay - there is no timer in browser-based javascript that will never suffer a delay (because JS is single threaded and timers don't interrupt running code).  What JasonP has suggested is the best you can do in JS.  Make an interval of something short like 250ms and then calculate the actual elapsed time on each tick.  That's basically the best one can do in browser JS.

Answer (score 1):

If the "lag in the Browser" is the Problem you COULD set up an webworker to do the timings and trigger certain events on the main page.

this is ALOT of overhead since webworker are pretty expensive, but could help you out.

Comment: The webworker would still need to wait for the main execution thread to be available before updating the display, wouldn't it?

Comment: the webworker is not able to update the display. it can send messages back to the main thread. therefore the main thread can update the display. during this update the main thread is blocked and incoming messages are cued up. if this is the case you can consider making calculations in the webworker thread.